# Dart Future.forEach: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: dart

I want to do a `forEach` loop on a `List` of `String` with an async operation.

So I wanted to use `Future.forEach` but it fails:

```dart
final List<String> alwaysRequiredFiles = ['some_path', 'other_path'];
        
await Future.forEach(alwaysRequiredFiles, (filepath) async {
   // this fails: error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable
   final file = File(filepath);

   return await file.delete();
});
```

I have a way to do it with a `for ... in` loop but I'd like to know why `Future.forEach` isn't working.

```
// this ways it works without an error
for (final filepath in alwaysRequiredFiles) {
   final file = File(filepath);

   await file.delete();
}
```

Here is a simple Dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=49e08930c99d9300d85a412ebd052bf5

Comment: Try with `Future.forEach<String>(`. This is one of these cases where Dart's type system can be a little stupid. :)

Comment: Yes thanks @julemand101, it fixed it. Dartpad showed me the way too!

Comment: (I think) the reason is Dart does not understand how it should guess the type of a parameter based on another parameter to the same method (it also comes with the question of what should the order then be?). So you need to tell it explicit when using certain methods like `Future.forEach`. (yet another reason to go for the for-each solution, that you have already written, if possible)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Dartpad gave me a hint: we have to cast the `T element` as a `String`.

This works:

```dart
final List<String> alwaysRequiredFiles = ['some_path', 'other_path'];
        
// note the `String` before `filepath`
await Future.forEach(alwaysRequiredFiles, (String filepath) async {
   final file = File(filepath);

   return await file.delete();
});
```